# How to avoid ambiguous field while reusing query shorthand in Yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have table like below.

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    id INT,
    relationId INT,
    status INT
)


CREATE TABLE B (
    id INT,
    status INT
)
```

The class file is like below

```
class A extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {
    public function getB() {
        return $this->hasOne(B::class, ['id' => 'relationId']);
    }

    public function find() {
        return new AQuery(__CLASS__);
    }
}

class AQuery extends \yii\db\Query {
    public function isActive() {
        return $this->andWhere(['status' => 1]);
    }
    public function isNotActive() {
        return $this->andWhere(['status' => 0]);
    }
}

class B extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {
    public function find() {
        return new BQuery(__CLASS__);
    }
}

class BQuery extends \yii\db\Query {
    public function isActive() {
        return $this->andWhere(['status' => 1]);
    }
    public function isNotActive() {
        return $this->andWhere(['status' => 0]);
    }
}
```

I'm doing something like this

```
$model = A::find()
            ->joinWith([
                'b' => function(BQuery $query) {
                     $query->isNotActive();
                }
            ])
            ->isActive()
            ->one();
```

This will produce error

```
Column 'status' in where clause is ambiguous"
```

The only way I know is to manually add alias to `$query->from` and rewrite the `$query->andWhere`. But is there any easier way to reuse the query shorthand?

Comment: Using `alias` for the field

Comment: you can use alias name for table and use that alias name in column names

Comment: How to use the `alias`?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ActiveRecord::tableName()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#tableName%28%29-detail) instead of aliasing (which doesn't seem to be an active record feature in Yii2). The `tableName()` can be accessed through the [`modelClass`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait.html#$modelClass-detail) property of `\yii\db\ActiveQuery`.

```
public function isActive() {
    $modelClass = $this->modelClass;
    return $this->andWhere([$modelClass::tableName().'.status' => 1]);
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `tableName` is not a part of `ActiveQuery`. Plus if we use this, the query will be broken once we use manual aliasing.

Comment: Yes. I had assumed that your functions were in your Model. My bad.

Comment: I have updated my answer, assuming you are using `ActiveQuery` instead of `Query`. It still doesn't take care of manual aliasing though.

Answer (score 0):

You can enhance your `isActive()` method to accept aliases with an optionnal parameter. You can try something like this:

```
class AQuery extends \yii\db\Query {
    protected function getAlias($alias = null) {
        return $alias !== null ? $alias : A::tableName();
    }

    public function isActive($alias = null) {
        $alias = $this->getAlias($alias);
        return $this->andWhere(["{$alias}.status" => 1]);
    }

    public function isNotActive($alias = null) {
        $alias = $this->getAlias($alias);
        return $this->andWhere(["{$alias}.status" => 0]);
    }
}
```